Why is the Cosine Similarity Low in My Semantic Engine Using Cohere?
I want to create a semantic engine. I'm using cohere in this way, but it seems to me that the cosine_similarity is too low in this example:
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

texts = ["The Bauhaus was a school of art, architecture and design established in Weimar, Germany in 1919. It was founded by architect Walter Gropius, and its aim was to bring together the fields of art, craft, and technology to create a new form of design that was both functional and aesthetically pleasing. It is famous for the Wassily Chair.", "Industrial design"]

response = client.embed(
    texts=texts,
    model='embed-english-v3.0',
    input_type='search_document'
)

embeddings = response.embeddings

[sentence1, sentence2] = embeddings

# 0.0 means no similarity, 1.0 means identical
sim = cosine_similarity([sentence1], [sentence2])

Why the embedding model works in this way? Am I missing something else to do for obtaining a better correlation?
Thank you

but it seems to me that the cosine_similarity is too low in this example you have never reported them
